# Cordova Android App's Version Number Changes in Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I am trying to submit my App, and the version does not come out as expected, always append the number 8 on the Playstore (which results to 30203**8**)

I already tried removing and adding the same Android platform. Changing the version from Android Studio's Project Structure seems to not help either.. Where else should I look?

I would really appreciate any advise, thanks in advance

Cordova: 6.0.0

Android Platform: 4.1.1

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id=.. version="3.2.03" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
    ..bla
    </description>
    <author email="a@a.com" href="http://www.web.com">
        Author
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value ="16" />
        <preference name="Orientation" value="sensorLandscape" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <!--<preference name="android-hardwareAccelerated" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" /> -->
    </platform>
</widget>
```

**Edit**
To make the fix run every build, I made a hook in config.xml just below the platform tag:

```
...
<platform name="android">
        <hook type="before_build" src="scripts/androidVersionFix.js" />
...
```

at the scripts folder, the androidVersionFix.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/*

----the file creates:-----------
 # In <your-project>/platforms/android/gradle.properties
  cdvVersionCode=30203
---------------------------------
where 30203 is the android-versionCode from config.xml


*/

var configXml = 'config.xml'; 

var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var appVersion = '';
var fileContents = function() {
    return "#Android version code fix:  In <your-project>/platforms/android/gradle.properties \\n \
cdvVersionCode="+appVersion
};
var command = "sed -n 's/.*android-versionCode=\"\\([^\"]*\\).*/\\1/p' ";


    exec(command + configXml, function(e,out,err){ 
        appVersion = out;
        console.log('echo creating gradle.properties, app Version: ' + appVersion);
        exec('echo "'+fileContents()+'" > ./platforms/android/gradle.properties');
    });
```

Comment: It will take whatever `VersionCode` you have defined in your `Build.Gradle`.

Comment: I have only defined the VersionCode  through config.xml, where Cordova writes down to the AndroidManifest. The Build.gradle was generated automatically. I tried changing the following line from the Build.gradle

//ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)
ext.cdvVersionCode = 30203;

But after generating a signed apk, I ran a search throughout the project and a variable keeps getting assigned to 302038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its a problem of `build.gradle` from there its fetching and do not edit `build.gradle`. Do one thing create gradle.properties file in platform/android and paste this `cdvVersionCode=3.2.03` statement to `gradle.properties`. It should work

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my problem. I tried @Ghandi's answer, and after comment the block of code mentioned, it still append a different digit **0**, though  his info was really helpful. For the contents of my gradle.properties, I put 30203 instead of 3.2.03. The latter results to build errors during Cordova build

Comment: No that is not the good idea, dont edit the build.gradle directly if you want to edit the build.gradle follow below link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/tools.html about build.gradle. Really it will cause while updating your app @niCad

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an unresolved bug in cordova 5.0.0 and above. This link has more [info](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8976?jql=text%20~%20%22versionCode%22) on the same. After having looking at the build.gradle file under platforms\android folder, the following code seems to be doing the manipulation of version number,

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
```

To get away from the problem, you may remove the offending code build.gradle which does not cause any harm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update inside AndroidManifest.xml, not config.xml.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer but the Manifest displays the correct version code as well. Somewhere when building the app that it still go wrong..


`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:versionCode="30203" android:versionName="3.2.03" package="com.app.appName" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`